# Visual Studio 2022 Highlight Matching Brackets

Tags: text-editor, visual-studio-2022

I installed Visual Studio 2022 and I can't seem to figure out how to turn on highlighting for matching braces. It was working in Visual Studio 2019 and seemed like it was the default but it's not working for Visual Studio 2022. What setting do I change?

I've tried changing Tools → Options → Environment (Show settings for "Text Editor") → Fonts and Color → Brace Matching (Highlight and Rectangle) because I read that the default colors are very nuance and hard to notice, but still nothing.

Should I just try reinstalling?

As you can see, it highlights key words and other places in the code where those words match up, but not the brackets. Same result no matter which side of the bracket I click on:

[image: highlight on type but not on bracket]

Comment: Which language or document type are you having this difficulty?  And which workloads have you installed?

Comment: .cs files in C#
It was a fresh install so there shouldn't have been any workloads.
I reinstalled it and that seamed to fix the issue, thanks for the reply!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: did you ever find the solution? having the same issue with a .js file